# Custom IsInRole() when using Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-core

To maintain compatibility with existing applications I was planing on using *Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Identity*, as described in the documentation:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

This seems to work as expected as far as logging a user in, but I'm having issues with roles -- specifically when using the `[Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]`.

In the code below, I can call `p.IsInRole("ADMIN")` and my implementation of `MyClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole()` is called and returns true.

What doesn't work is the `[Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]` attribute because it ends up calling `ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole` (which returns False) instead of `MyClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole()` (which returns True).

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
public class MyAdminController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var p = new MyClaimsPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal.Current);

        bool isAdmin = p.IsInRole("ADMIN");

        return View();
    }
}
```

1. When not using Identity and only using *Cookie Middleware*, can I use the `[Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]` attribute?
2. How? :-)

If I had to guess, I'm not implementing `p.IsInRole()` correctly -- currently this method loads the roles, then returns a True/False. Perhaps I have to 'load' my roles elsewhere in such a way that the `ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole` is sufficient. If I was using Identity(), I assume this would be an implementation of `IUserRoleStore`.

My other 'if i had to guess' answer is that somewhere in startup.cs I need to replace the current `ClaimsPrincipal` with an instance of `MyClaimsPrincipal`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add role claims when cookie is created.

In startup.cs:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
     options.AuthenticationScheme = "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance";
     options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/");
     options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/");
     options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
     options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
 });
```

And login post method may be something like this(i assume that you have a custom login page):

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(string userName, string password, string returnUrl)
{
     var user = _userService.GetUser(userName, password);// i assume that  _userService is injected
     if (user == null)
     {
          //return Error;
     }
     var claims = new List<Claim>()
     {
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
          new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.GetFullName() ),
     };
     var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Forms");
     identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "ADMIN"));
     var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

     HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", principal);
     return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```